# Facebook login on iOS crashes my app

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, safari, crash

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook SDK into my iOS app. To log in I'm calling:

```
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                 }];
```

In the iOS 6.0 simulator it opens Safari and after I click "Okay" it returns to my app to the completion handler, but when I try to run it on my device (also iOS 6.0) it opens Safari and crashes my app so when I click "Okay" in Safari it restarts the app from scratch so it needs to log in again.

The interesting thing is that when I run the Scrumptious sample on my device which logs in in the same way it works just fine. I've gone over the configuration of both projects but I can't find a reason why it works in Scrumptious but not in my app.

Comment: Put NSLog inside completionHandler and see what is the exact error device showing.

Comment: Since the app crashes it doesn't return to the completionHandler..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my app didn't crash because of facebook. My app is an OpenGL game and I did not stop the OpenGL properly when the app went to the background, causing the OpenGL to crash the game when facebook opened Safari.

Comment: Plus one, made me realize the Facebook call wasn't the problem for me either